# Outlook 2016 on macOS: Native Add-in, how to proceed

Tags: macos, outlook-addin, outlook-restapi, outlook-2016, outlook-for-mac

**Problem Statement**: Create a macOS Outlook add-in which responds to Calendar move and delete events and calls an API.

**Challenge:** Most of the links say that this is not possible but there are native Outlook add-ins for Mac already out there. One example is Zoom's [New Updates For Outlook Plugin](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/203254295-New-Updates-for-Outlook-Plugin).

[image: How Zoom Plugin appears on an appointment window]
[image: How Zoom Plugin reacts to when an appointment is moved in calendar]

**Problem with Office-JS add-in:** We know that MS is pushing office add-ins for Mac, however there are some limitations which we cannot live with. Office-JS add-in does not react on move and delete events in a Calendar. I understand that there are notifications that can be subscribed to and required action can be taken. This is also a challenge because our clients won't allow to deploy extra components outside network.

**Does anyone have any idea on how to create a native macOS Outlook add-in?**

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility Updated with screenshots to show that Zoom plugin seems to be a native one.

Comment: Hi Rohit, Was you lucky to get more information on above?

Answer (score 0):

The add-in you've given as an example isn't a native add-in. It is a web add-in using Office.js. It does not seem to react to events in the Calendar. It is configured for the Calendar read / write surface, so its button appears in that context.

Currently, there is no way to create "native" add-ins for Mac Outlook. If you can describe your scenario and what you aren't able to achieve with web add-ins, we could try and provide a workaround.

Comment: I have added screenshots to show that Zoom Plug-in is not an Office add-in.  Scenerio which we are trying to add is : Call an Internal Deployed API when a meeting is created, Deleted and Moved in Outlook calendar.

Comment: Hi @Mac-Outlook-Extensibility, Yes it looks like Zoom and Webex plugins for Mac OS are natively developed, but everywhere there is only recommended way to develop such plugins is web-addin only. I am also struggling with so many issues with web addin for Mac platform, and not getting any help on them from MSFT people. It is very disappointing.

Comment: The native add-in model is not supported by outlook  Mac and hence no documentation on this. The suggested method is to use the web based model. @KanakSony, kindly let us know what are the issues faced by you and we shall try to resolve those.

Comment: Hi, We have couple of issues - 
1.) How can we create .msi /.exe for windows and .pkg /.dmg for Mac distribution - Zoom/webex is having installers and these apps are not distributed via office store.
After installation, there code is installed on machines, but in case of web addin - code stays on server.
2.) Web addin ribbon button does not activates (and remains grey out) until User selects a message (this is mentioned in API documentation) 
but zoom controls remains activated always.

(continued in next comment....)

Comment: 3.) Zoom for outlook Mac has - a custom button on the header part of meeting/appointment near Location/Subject/Duration/Starts/Ends .How to do that? (image link for reference)?  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S1SPciql32PQ7xLjpXoLUzQDiNdXbWgm

4.) Outlook addin performance is very slow after deploying on EC2 instance. T2.Medium - server location is US.

Comment: @KanakSony, all the capabilities that you mentioned here are not approved capability. As I mentioned earlier,  the Zoom integration is not using any API or capability provided by outlook. Only web add-in is the approved way of building integration.